# Multithreading freezes

Tags: python, multithreading, curl, pool

i have a little problem with the following code:

```
def getTextFromURL(url):
    req = pycurl.Curl()
    print "URL: "+ str(url)
    req.setopt(pycurl.URL, url)
    req.setopt(pycurl.HTTPHEADER, ["Accept:"])
    req.setopt(pycurl.CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5)
    req.setopt(pycurl.TIMEOUT, 10)
    req.setopt(pycurl.NOSIGNAL, 1)
    resultStream = StringIO.StringIO()
    req.setopt(pycurl.WRITEFUNCTION, resultStream.write)
    try: 
        req.perform()
        text = BeautifulSoup(resultStream.getvalue()).get_text()
        return text
    except BaseException as e:
        print type(e)
        return ''

def addTextToTask(newTask):
    newTask.fullText = getTextFromURL(newTask.url)
    return newTask


def createTasks(sources):
    newTasks = []
    for source in sources:
        newTask = models.Task(title = source.title, url = source.url, fullText = None)
        newTasks.append(newTask)
    pool = Pool(4)
    fullTasks = pool.map(addTextToTask, newTasks)
    pool.close()
    pool.join() 
    for fullTask in fullTasks:
        db.session.add(fullTask)
    db.session.commit()
    return True
```

When i call the createTasks()-function it works fine, with less than 100 sources. If i call it with more than 100 sources it starts getting slower and finally freezes. I don't get any error-messages.

Comment: What are "Pool" and "models"? Is this multiprocessing.Pool? If so, you are better off passing simpler data than a Task object which could involve pickling a lot of data. Suppose you pass just the url to pool.map and play the Task/db game on the result?

Comment: Yes, it's multiprocessing.Pool, "models" is my SQLAlchemy-Model. I tried your suggestion, to go straight to getTextfromUrl() in the pool.map() without changing anything in the db(just for test purposes), but the problem still remains.